# How to write a text above a line created by \rule?

Tags: rules, line

How to write my name under the line created by the following code?

```
Name: \hspace{8pt} \rule{5cm}{1pt}
```

Is this possible without any major alteration?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you mean `\underline{my name}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The title of your question suggests you want to add text above the line, the body of your questions mentions wanting to add text below the line. Which of the two do you actually want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\rule[raise-height]{width}{height}`

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
    
    Name above:
    
     \rule[10pt]{5cm}{1pt}  
     
     \bigskip
     
    \rule[-2pt]{5cm}{1pt}   
      
    Name bellow:         
     
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great hack! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Old topic, but…

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\signature}[2]{% #1 = width, #2 = text
  \parbox[t]{#1}{\footnotesize\centering\hrulefill\\#2\\[2ex]}%
}

\begin{document}

X \signature{5cm}{myself} X

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you're interested in the following output:

[image]

You could use a `tabular` in order to place the name below the line. In order to adjust the horizontal alignment od 2my name"  with repsect to the line, adjust the column specifier of the second column to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}     % left aligned
Name: & \rule{5cm}{1pt} \\
      & my name
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lc}     % centered
Name: & \rule{5cm}{1pt} \\
      & my name
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lr}     % right aligned
Name: & \rule{5cm}{1pt} \\
      & my name
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for an effect similar to this:

[image: form with text underlined]

This can be done using the following trick:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{l l}
   密级 & \rule{5em}{0.5pt} \\
   学校代码 & \parbox{5em}{\centering 10497\hrule} \\
\end{tabular}
```

In this code, `\parbox` is creating a box that can accept multiple lines and has a fixed width. So, we can insert the text followed by an `\hrule` and it will be directly under it.

Answer (score 0):

Left aligned text with bold and serif font and with line under it. Line has fixed length here 0.275 times \textwidth. Vertical space between text and line has 2 pt and line has height of 0.05 mm.

```
\parbox{0.275\textwidth}{\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{sl} Foo foo foo \vspace{2pt} \hrule height 0.05mm }
```

[image]